# Update is being executed before BulkInsert

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I wrote a program to insert some records using sqlCopy for faster processing, and then the code executes and update statement [on an other table] based on the newly inserted records.

Problem is that the update almost always executes before the insert! [about 2 seconds before.. according to the time-stamps of the insert and update rows.] the only way I could make the update execute after the insert is to put the code asleep for 2-3 seconds.. Is there a better way to make sure the insert completes before the code continues?

I even captured the RowsCopied event, the rows are instantly copied 'before' the update. but in the database the update gets in earlier.

```
     bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table)

     Dim Sql = "Update tbl Set Total = (select sum(qty) from Inserttbl where inId = ID)"
     ExecuteSQL(Sql)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `bulkCopy.Options` the TableLock...?

Comment: Are the bulkCopy and the ExecuteSQL using the same connection? If so, based on MSDN this is impossible. BTW, I checked out some example of SqlBulkCopy and those codes are using  "USING" statement. Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: WriteToServer is synchronous.  I suggest you run a SQL trace to see the actual requests being sent to SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks all for your help in resolving that matter! every comment helped a lot in getting to the ultimate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem... the insert timestamp was provided by the client, while the update timestamp came from the server. The clients time is 2 seconds earlier then the servers time..

I changed both should use the servers getDate function. problem solved.